# Not able to get Master Page Control's value at first Page Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/__.Master" %>
```

to embed my master page content into child page to access control belong to Master Page.

I have one `DropDownList` in Master page. And I want to access its `SelectedValue` in my Child Page.

Problem is when page first time loads
and as I am trying to access DropDownList's Selected Value by writing in child Page - "`Master.DropDownList.SelectedValue`".

I am not able to get DropDownList's Value. Its display's Blank.

But When `Page.IsPostBack` I am able to get `SelectedValue` of that `DropDownList`.

Is there any Method to resolve this problem.

Comment: probably is synchronization problem, you try to get the selectvalue, before the control have it. Debug and step on your code to see that.

Comment: could you please show us code - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

source http://forums.asp.net/t/1511003.aspx/1
The following is the sequence in which events occur when a master page is merged with a content page:

Master page controls Init event.

Content controls Init event.

Master page Init event.

Content page Init event.

Content page Load event.

Master page Load event.

Content controls Load event.

Content page PreRender event.

Master page PreRender event.

Master page controls PreRender event.

Content controls PreRender event.

so if you load the values into the drop in the the Master's Page_Load this is the reason, your Page_Load comes before the Masters Page_Load

Comment: I was trying to access Master Page Control's value in Page_Load Event. that's why I was not able to get its value. Thnx Ahaliav Fox.